# Add an Android Studio / IntelliJ project to a code.google.com project with git

Tags: android, git, intellij-idea

So, I have an Android Studio (IntelliJ) project for an app I'm writing. I'd like to add it to a project I've created on code.google.com. How do I do that without having to clone the repository to a new project directory and then push all my AS project files into it?

I see that I can almost do this with **VCS > Checkout from Version Control > Git** and specify a Git repository URL, but AS forces me to create a new, empty directory when I do this.

How do I setup Git source control with code.google.com as my remote repository, without having to move my existing project files around in the file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so the best solution I've come up with is to create a local git repository, create a code.google.com git project, and then manually connect the local repository to the code.google.com project. Note that this requires git to be installed on your development machine.

1. Create the app project in Android Studio.
2. Select the root project folder.
3. Select **VCS > Import into Version Control > Create Git Repository**
4. Select project folder to create a git repository.
   Now the project is under source control.
5. Create a project at code.google.com using git source control.
6. Go to the **Source > Checkout** page of the project and get the clone URL.
7. Open a terminal and navigate to the project directory.
8. Modify the local git repository to connect the remote repository on code.google.com:

   git remote add origin https://my-user-name%40code.google.com/p/my-project-name/
9. Add files to the repository and commit them using the Android Studio interface or the git command-line interface, e.g.;

   git add files-for-source-control.ext

   git commit .
10. Finally, push the commit to the remote server:

    git push origin master

Comment: It works perfectly, only when I push a commit from Android Studio I get the message: "Nothing to push" from Android Studio

Comment: (As addition to last reply), via command line I can push to the server even when Android Studio says 'Nothing to push'

Answer (score 0):

@ObAt,
If you find *Nothing to push* message on Android studio, Try this method
Got to
VCS > Git > Push
and Select the tick box for *"Push Current Branch to Alternative branch"* and click Push button